# NMEA HDOP value coming empty in Android

Tags: android, gps, nmea

In Android, I have implemented NMEAListener along with onNMEAReceived() method. In this I am getting GPGGA string like:

GPGGA,235942.000,2245.0750,N,07551.9900,E,0,0,,209.4,M,-59.4,M,,*67

In this, sometimes I am getting HDOP (token[8]) i.e. accuracy as empty like above. 
So, please help me with the values of HDOP when it is blank or show some value and also if any condition to be implemented for the empty parameter.

Comment: You have to add programming language and android to the tags. No one will see the question otherwise.

Comment: I am also facing same issue.